# I had try to run a car game through c++ only

Tags: c++

As mentioned in the title I try to run a car game developed using only CPP but faced problems in line 20 of my code...

```
#include<conio.h>
#include<dos.h> 
#include <windows.h>
#include <time.h>

#define SCREEN_WIDTH 90
#define SCREEN_HEIGHT 26
#define WIN_WIDTH 70 

using namespace std; 

HANDLE console = GetStdHandle(STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE);
COORD CursorPosition;

int enemyY[3];
int enemyX[3];
int enemyFlag[3];
char car[1][1] = {{' ',' '},
               {'*','*','*'}};//<--------------------here
int carPos = WIN_WIDTH/2;
int score = 0; 

void gotoxy(int x, int y){
 CursorPosition.X = x;
 CursorPosition.Y = y;
 SetConsoleCursorPosition(console, CursorPosition);
}
void setcursor(bool visible, DWORD size) {
 if(size == 0)
     size = 20;  
 
 CONSOLE_CURSOR_INFO lpCursor;   
 lpCursor.bVisible = visible;
 lpCursor.dwSize = size;
 SetConsoleCursorInfo(console,&lpCursor);
}
```

in my code error is poping as
<>

will anybody help me to find an error in my code?

Comment: my further code is: ```void drawBorder(){  
 for(int i=0; i<SCREEN_HEIGHT; i++){
  for(int j=0; j<17; j++){
   gotoxy(0+j,i); cout<<"Â±";
   gotoxy(WIN_WIDTH-j,i); cout<<"Â±";
  }
 } 
 for(int i=0; i<SCREEN_HEIGHT; i++){
  gotoxy(SCREEN_WIDTH,i); cout<<"Â±";
 } 
}
void genEnemy(int ind){
 enemyX[ind] = 17 + rand()%(33);  
}```

Comment: Please edit your original post and include that snippet of code.  Also, please include the error.

Comment: Total number of element of `car[1][1]` is 1.

Comment: Use `std::array` if length is fixed or `std::vector` if length is dynamic.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're defining your 'car' array as a 2d (1x1) array, which would need to be initialized like:

```
char car[1][1] = {{' '}}; // probably not useful (it only holds 1 char)
```

You probably need to change the size of your array. Something like:

```
char car[2][3] = {     // here car is 2x3, an array of size 2 
    { ' ', ' ', ' ' }, // each element is an array of size 3
    { '*', '*', '*' }
}
```

In the future, it will be helpful if you also post the error that you're getting.